# What kind of shape is used to depict a media converter on a network diagram?

Tags: networking, visio

I'm familiar with all the standard Cisco shapes to depict various types of switches and routers.  I've also come up with a pretty good shape to show encryption devices.  I'm having a hard time trying to come up with something that would show a media converter (Ethernet to fiber and vice versa) on my network drawings using Visio.  Do anyone know of a standard shape that's used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no true "standard" symbol/shape for a media converter, since that is generally viewed as an interface-level item. Most network diagrams tend to show entire devices instead of individual interfaces, and leave Layer 1 connections as a simple line.

If I were to come up with a symbol, I would probably avoid use of standard electronic diagram ones and instead opt for a simple labeled box or ellipse, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: That is an interesting point of view.  So you don't show physical media converters or use different types of lines to denote copper vs. fiber vs. serial cables?  I find myself having to do this now that I have both fiber and copper Gigabit interfaces.  I used to be able to tell just by looking at the port number where a gi was fiber and an fa was copper.  I also have multiple places where a workstation is too far away from a switch (not my decision) so I have a media converter near the switch and another one near the workstation.

Comment: That's a much deeper level of detail for a network diagram than I think most places use. If I wanted to do something like that, however, I would just use different color lines for different physical media types. Orange is fiber and blue is copper, for example. A media converter could be a simple circle with orange coming in one side and blue coming out the other. Heck, make a little circle with a symbol for "SX/Cu" or "SX/T" to make it clear that it's converting from 1000BASE-SX to Copper.

Comment: I like the idea of using a symbol with SX/T.  I think I'll use a box with SX on one side and T on the other.  Thanks.